# Convert double string back to double

Tags: .net, c#-3.0

```
var doubleMaxValueString = double.MaxValue.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

and I want to convert it back to double, so I'm doing like this:

```
var doubleMaxValue = double.Parse(doubleMaxValueString, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

but it doesn't work...

how can I convert it back to double?

thanks!

Edit:
it throws: OverflowExceptionValue: was either too large or too small for a Double.

I'm using var because it's more practical =)

Comment: Can you be more specific than "doesn't work"? Is it throwing an exception? Are you not getting the value you expect? Unrelated: I'm also curious as to why you're choosing to use `var` in these cases, since you know what the types returned by both of those functions will be (but maybe someone else can provide a little insight on that one).

Comment: Why are you doing this?  Why wouldn't you just use `double.MaxValue` in the second example?

Comment: I'm creating a system where the user can type a value and select its type, in this case, I've got this error while testing... that's why... I just wanted to understand why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can find good explanation [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WhyYouCantDoubleParseDoubleMaxValueToStringOrSystemOverloadExceptionsWhenUsingDoubleParse.aspx). Basically the problem is that while converting `double` to `string` we're rounding it up so it exceeds `double.MaxValue`. You can fix for example in this way:

```
var doubleMaxValueString = double.MaxValue.ToString("R", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
var doubleMaxValue = double.Parse(doubleMaxValueString, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

More information on "R" argument and why it helps may be found [here on msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx#RFormatString)